# The extension of an invertible ideal to the ring of fractions is an invertible ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $I$ be an invertible ideal of a domain $R$, $S \subseteq R$ a multiplicative subset of $R$. Then $I_S$ is an invertible ideal of $R_S$ .

My attempt looks as follows: Since $I^{-1}$ is also an ideal we have

$$I^{-1}_S = \bigg\{ \frac{j}{s} \in R_S \mid j \in I^{-1} \bigg\} .$$

Thus we obtain

$$I^{-1}_S I_S = \bigg\{ \frac{ij}{s} \in R_S \mid i \in I_S, j \in I^{-1} \bigg\}  = \bigg\{ \frac{r}{s} \in R_S \mid r \in R \bigg\} = R_S$$

Here are the relevant definitions and elementary properties:

> Let $R$ be a domain and let $S \subset R$ be a multiplicatively closed with $0 \not \in S$. The ***ring of fractions $R$ with denomiators of  in $S$*** is denoted by $R_S$. Let further be $I \subseteq R$ be an ideal of $R$. We denote the ***extension from $I$ to $R_S$*** with $I_S$. It can be shown that
>
> $$I_S = \bigg\{ \frac{i}{s} \in R_S \mid i \in I \bigg\}.$$
>
> At last we define be the canonical homomorphism between $R$ and $R_S$ to be $$f_s : R \rightarrow R_S, r \mapsto \frac{rs}{s} \text{ for some } s \in S.$$
> If $M$ is an $R$-module then the $R_S$-module $M_S$ is analogously defined to $R_S$. Similarly the map $g: M \rightarrow M_S, m \mapsto \frac{ms}{s} \text{ for some } s \in S$ is an $R$-module homomorphism

Could you please tell me if I am right?

Comment: Your general approach is correct, though you should write out in more detail exactly where you’re applying what and why the inclusions go both ways.

Comment: No, you are not right. First of all, if by ideal you mean a subset of $R$ with some properties, then $I^{-1}$ is not an ideal. It is an $R$-submodule of the field of fractions of $R$. Moreover, the product of two "ideals" is not the set of the products of their elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $I$ is invertible there is $J$ an $R$-submodule of $K$ (the field of fractions of $R$), in fact a [fractional ideal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_ideal), such that $IJ=R$. Then $(IJ)_S=R_S$. Now show that $(IJ)_S=I_SJ_S$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question a bit, please see above. I now understand that my idea of a product of ideal was wrong. Since as you said $I^{-1}$ is a submodule and $I$ is an ideal we should have, if I am not mistaking, $I_SJ_S = \{\sum_{i=1}^n am \mid a \in I_S, m \in J_, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. However, I do not understand how we can derive $(IJ)_S=I_SJ_S$ from that. Could that it is because $f_s$ and $g$ as written above are homomorphisms?

Comment: $R$ is not unitary? $S$ is not supposed to contain $1$? I am asking since usually $f_S(r)=r/1$.

Comment: Anyway, think about the way one writes an element from $(IJ)_S$ and similarly for elements from $I_SJ_S$. I think the last ones are written as sums of products of elements of the form $a/s$ and $b/t$ with $a\in I$, $b\in J$ and $s,t\in S$. This has nothing to do with the homomorphisms f and g.